#  How to center text in tabhost?

Tags: android, center, android-tabhost, vertical-alignment

I have a basic question. In many tabhost examples, we find tabs with image and text.

In my case, I would like to only display a text, but the issue is that my text is horizontally centered but not vertically (The text is at the bottom of my tab).

I tried  : android:layout_gravity="center" in the framelayout, but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea, please ?

My xml.

```
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

solved : I customized my tabs thanks to the following tutorial : http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Thank you

Comment: The same question was asked a long time ago. Please read this issue [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164443/how-to-center-align-text-in-a-tab-bar-in-android)

Comment: Yes, I saw this post, but I still have the issue. :(

Comment: Its better to use a custom tab as default tabs has size of icons and text both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center align text in a tab bar in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164443/how-to-center-align-text-in-a-tab-bar-in-android)

Comment: Thank you.you're right. I customized my tabs thanks to the following tutorial : http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Answer (score 4):

1. Try to get the tab titles first and set gravity and layouts explicitly as shown below:

   ```
   TextView textView = (TextView)tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
   .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
   textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);        
   textView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
   textView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
   ```

   Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it dosen't work. My text still is at the bottom of my tab. Does it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below to code to make tab text in center:

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param=new

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

```
    param.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
            .findViewById(android.R.id.title); // Unselected Tabs
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#505050"));
    tv.setTextSize(10);
    tv.setLayoutParams(param);
```