# vertically center text in tabs

Tags: android

How do I center the text vertically in tabs within a TabHost? The text sits at the bottom right now. I seemed to have tried everything but nothing works.

I've tried using things like android:layout_gravity="center" and android:gravity="center" but they do nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your TabHost xml?

Comment: Similar issue, it is solved perfectly by se.solovyev

see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8596771/720489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people ask it without solution . The best thing I can suggest you is to make your custom tabHost. Like [this](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)

Comment: didn't work, i made the same thing but with buttons and a layout lol

Answer (score 0):

See the answer from kocus to my question [Controlling Tab colour-state / size in a TabActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407300/controlling-tab-colour-state-size-in-a-tabactivity). It's not exactly what you want but it explains how to customize Tabs and hopefully it will help.